# Open GL 3D library for iOS (and Android)?

Tags: android, ios, opengl-es, 3d

Is there some free and easy to use 3D library for iOS (and Android) that simplifies Open GL ES framework. Just like there is cool WebGL library: [ThreeJS](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/) for javascript.

So far I saw [Unity](http://unity3d.com/) but it's not free and I would like something simplified.

My usage would be setting the scene, meshes, camera, rotating the camera etc...

Comment: I'll vote this for off-topic as it is not really a code problem, more of a programmer decision problem that might be better suited for programmers.stackexchange.com.

Comment: I understand, I'll post a question there also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to go with Cocos3D because it has all the features I need and is similar to JS libraries. It is free and you don't have to use any special engines with it.

Answer (score 1):

For Android you can use AndEngine which supports GL ES1 and GL ES2. For IOS you can use Cocos2D.

Comment: Cocos2d is for 2D graphic rendering. I think you meant Cocos3d.

Comment: Look at this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4227759/android-game-engine-for-2d-and-3d-games

Answer (score 0):

One option I believe is  [SiO2](http://sio2interactive.com/).. And [Oolong](http://code.google.com/p/oolongengine/) too.. I once played with blender and SiO2 and it went well..If you are only interested in 2D games only then [Cocos2D](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/) is best bet for iphone.. 
For android [AndEngine](http://www.andengine.org/) is good,and I believe SiO2 works for android too..

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is [Sparrow](http://gamua.com/sparrow/) for iOS, and as for Android you can consider [AndEngine](http://www.andengine.org/)
(easier) or [LibGDX](https://code.google.com/p/libgdx/) (faster).

Answer (score 0):

Ahh, Unity did [give away](http://www.blendernation.com/2012/03/07/non-blender-get-free-unity-licenses-for-ios-and-android/) the iOS/Android versions back in March/April this year - maybe if you asked them nicely?

[OpenSceneGraph](http://openscenegraph.com) has a large and active following in the Vis/Sim community, and is starting to creep into games, here's a couple iOS/game related topics from their forums:

http://forum.openscenegraph.org/viewtopic.php?t=10291

http://forum.openscenegraph.org/viewtopic.php?t=10308  (p.2 of this thread has links to a couple osg-based games in the iTunes store)

Comment: As the matter of fact, I did downloaded that free version of Unity but I see all those engines as to big form my need. What I need is a 'simple libray' like ThreeJS for javascript. I think Cocos3D looks most promising and easier for now but I haven't had time to check all of this suggestions (and accept an answer).

Answer (score 0):

For Leaning very basic of open GL for iOs I would suggest to have a look at this http://antonholmquist.com/blog/opengl-es-2-0-ios-tutorial-getting-started/. This gives the basic idea of vertex and fragment shaders. After going through this a beginner can go through other tutorials which explains the detailed concepts of openGL.

I have gone through so many links but this one explains the basic really well.